# How to skip spaces and whitespaces in command line argument for python?

Tags: python

I have the following code for which I am trying to take it as argument.
a.py:-

```
import sys
try:
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#location for the xml file where parsing is required
param1 = sys.argv[1]
#parent tag of new tag
param2 = sys.argv[2]
param3 = sys.argv[3]
param4 = sys.argv[4]
print(param3)
#parse the config file
tree = ET.parse(param1)
#get the root of config file
root = tree.getroot()
#add element exactly at particular point
tar = param2
#this will find the root tag
target = tree.find(tar)
#new tag required to be inserted
seq = param3
#taking new tag element in element tree
temp = ET.Element(seq)
#insert the position where you want to enter
i = int(param4)
target.insert(i,temp)
temp.tail = '\n'
tree.write(param1,encoding='utf-8')
```

and another file to get the arguments as b.py:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import xmlparser.py
host1 = socket.getfqdn()
print(host1)
param1 = 'config.xml'
param2 = 'Target'
param3 = 'Attribute NAME="A" VALUE="((host={0},ip=123.0.0.0,port=22),(host= 
{0}, port=11),(host={0}, port=162))"'.format(host1)
param4 = 3

python xmlparser.py param1 param2 param3 param4
```

when i run "python b.py" I am getting error as Invalid syntax, Can anyone suggest what could be the error?

Comment: Can you please write the whole error statement that you are getting form the terminal?

Comment: File "b.py", line 11
    python xmlparser.py param1 param2 param3 param4
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Is `python xmlparser.py param1 param2 param3 param4` an actual line in your file, or something you're running afterwards?

Comment: As @dashiell said, if that is the a line inside your b.py, it will definitively give you an error. You should read the documentation for xmlparser for more info.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make the first file's code as a function and call in in the next file like this-

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def parser(p1,p2,p3,p4):
    param1 = p1
    param2 = p2
    param3 = p3
    param4 = p4
    print(param3)
    tree = ET.parse(param1)
    root = tree.getroot()
    tar = param2
    target = tree.find(tar)
    seq = param3
    temp = ET.Element(seq)
    i = int(param4)
    target.insert(i,temp)
    temp.tail = '\n'
    tree.write(param1,encoding='utf-8')
```

and then call this in your second file like this

```
import socket
import xmlparser
host1 = socket.getfqdn()
print(host1)
param1 = 'config.xml'
param2 = 'Target'
param3 = 'Attribute NAME="A" VALUE="((host={0},ip=123.0.0.0,port=22),(host= {0}, port=11),(host={0}, port=162))"'.format(host1)
param4 = 3

xmlparser.parser(param1,param2,param3,param4)
```

This should work.

Also, avoid using try for imports, it will lead to a problem if the import isn't successful anyway thus loosing the purpose.

Comment: Sure let me try it out....one more thing this how can I take  param3 as argument....my whole purpose was to create command line argument code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your last part is a shell command, not python, so it's invalid syntax.

If you want to provide a shell command, your test function to exercise it would be better factored in bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

host1="$(hostname -A)"
echo $host1
param1='config.xml'
param2='Target'
param3='Attribute NAME="A" VALUE="((host={0},ip=123.0.0.0,port=22),(host= 
'"$host1"', port=11),(host={0}, port=162))"'
param4=3

python xmlparser.py "$param1" "$param2" "$param3" "$param4"
```

You could also use subprocess.popen in your python code.